# View definition is null (QSYS.QADBXREF.DBXDFN)

Tags: view, db2

In `QSYS.QADBXREF` I can see all our views, but for a few of them the View defition (`DBXDFN`) is NULL.

The View works fine, so I'm assuming the definition exists somewhere. Can anyone help me locate it?

Also, it would be nice to know what could have caused it to be saved without the definition..?

Answer (score 0):

If the View is Encrypted, the definition would be null.
Check the View by Right clicking Properties->Encrypted true/false.
You might need a SQL decryptor to view the definition.